# how do I save a text in another text file python

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, printing, save

I'm in search for help.
I've generated a random text, but I want to save this output onto a new text file.
Can someone help me do that?

This is my code:

```
def write_random_text(self, amount):
        return re.sub(ur'[^a-zA-Z,. ]', '', u''.join([random.choice(list(self.text)) for i in range(amount)]))

print write_random_text(200)
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your code. It will make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: what is the random text?

Comment: This is my code:
`def write_random_text(self, amount):
        return re.sub(ur'[^a-zA-Z,. ]', '', u''.join([random.choice(list(self.text)) for i in range(amount)]))

print write_random_text(100)`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Open/Create a file 
with open("file.txt", "a") as file:
    # Write in file
    file.write("text here")
```

r = read 
w = write 
a = append

a: Add this line to a file, if that file already exists, else create the file. This one is the most used.

Comment: But does this save/create the new text file in the same folder as the program, and how do I title it?

Comment: Yes, the "a" will create the file if it doesn't exist already. If you use "w" it wil create a file as well, but also overwrite it if it already exists. The file in my example will be name: file.txt

Comment: aha, now I understand.
But what if I want to make 3 new text files from the same text?
  example:

Text file 1,
Text file 2,
Text file 3.

Comment: you don't need to call close that is why you use a context manager

Comment: Adjusted my code. You can read/write as much text files as you like. Just give them a different name. So not 'file' but 'file1' or something.

Comment: @py.codan, just use a for loop and str.format to create multiple files

Comment: Look at my code, and give me an example, because im lost.

Answer (score 0):

unless this is a method of a class I would suggest not using self:

```
def write_random_text(self, amount, n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        with open("file{}".format(i),'w') as f:        
            f.write(re.sub(ur'[^a-zA-Z,. ]', '', u''.join([random.choice(list(self.text)) for i in range(amount)])))
```

Using it in your class would be something like:

```
instance.write_random_text(4,3)
```

Comment: And how do I run it?

Whats this n?
The number of the text I want to save into?

Comment: n is how many different files you want to create, is this part of a class?

Comment: Yes, it's a part of a class.
I've tried but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: it definitely does work if you use it properly! You need to call it using your instance of the class

Comment: I get this error: `IOError: File not open for writing`

Comment: It just prints "None"

Comment: Yes you are creating files why would you need to return anything?

Comment: I can't find the files then?

Comment: They are created in your pwd